# Make a picture move in java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a picture that moves on a background, but I can only make a letter move around with the case loop. Can anyone help me fix my problem.

best regards 
Malte Bukrinski

```
public class FXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
       // Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frontierLand.fxml"));
        //Image img1 = new Image(new FileInputStream(C:\Users\Malte Bukrinski\Documents\GitHub\Projektarbejde-1.-Semester-Gruppe-05\World of Zuul Project\src\Map_Pictures\Char2.png))


        Pane pane = new Pane();
        //Image characterPicture = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("char2");
        Text text = new Text(20,20,"A"); 
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        pane.getChildren().add(text); 

        text.setOnKeyPressed(e -> { //Lambda expression 
            switch(e.getCode()){
                case DOWN: text.setY(text.getY() + 50); break;
                case UP: text.setY(text.getY() - 50); break;
                case LEFT: text.setX(text.getX()- 50); break;
                case RIGHT: text.setX(text.getX()+ 50); break;

                default:
                    if(e.getText().length() > 0)
                    {
                     text.setText(e.getText());
                    }
            }
        });




        primaryStage.setTitle("Kagearm");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
         //stage.setTitle("FrontierLand");
         //stage.setScene(scene);
         //stage.show();
        text.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I see some image related code in comments, but what`s exactly your problem? you cant load image? image dont chage coordinates?

Comment: I cant figure out the way to move an image like the way I can move the text around (Same idea just with a picture instead) The comments are my tries to get the picture to move instead of the text

Answer (score 0):

You can draw image on canvas or in imageView in javaFX, if you want to draw it like text in your example - it will be imageView

And also tie onKeyPressed to your scene

```
        Image characterPicture = new Image(new FileInputStream("D:/yourProjectPath/toImage.png"));
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(characterPicture);

        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> { //Lambda expression
            switch(e.getCode()){
                case DOWN: imageView.setY(imageView.getY() + 50);break;
                case UP: imageView.setY(imageView.getY() - 50); break;
                case LEFT: imageView.setX(imageView.getX()- 50); break;
                case RIGHT: imageView.setX(imageView.getX()+ 50); break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try that out